# Error displayed when trying to insert data from db into dropdown list within CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

The following error is displayed:.............................................

```
    Severity: Notice
    Message:  Undefined variable: groups
    Filename: views/content_view.php
    Line Number: 10
```

please can you assist me...below is the code that i have tried

below is my controller

```
**MY CONTROLLER**

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Delivery_controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model_get');

    }
    public function delivery()
    {
        $data['groups'] = $this->model_get->getAllGroups();
        $this->load->view("site_header");
        $this->load->view("site_nav");
        $this->load->view('login');
        $this->load->view('content_view');  
        $this->load->view("content_video");
        $this->load->view("site_footer");
    }


}
?>

below is my view
**MY VIEW**


<div id="content" class="col-md-6">

            <h1> Comparison</h1> 


             <select class="form-control">
                            <?php 

                            if (is_array($groups))
                                {
                                    foreach($groups as $row)
                                    { 
                                      echo '<option value="'.$row->page.'">'.$row->page.'</option>';
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>


            </select>

</div>
```

below is the relevant information from the model
**MY MODEL**

```
        class Model_get extends CI_Model{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getAllGroups()
    {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT page FROM pageData');


        return $query->result();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->load->view('content_view', $data);
```

Comment: Good! Please check my answer as having solved your problem :)